# is there a way to get the index for multiple lists python?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, python-3.x, indexing

Thanks for checking out my question.

I was wondering how one such as myself may locate the index of two separate lists from within a for loop, am aware that you can do so with 1 list using enumerate, and that you can go through multiple elements via the zip method, but is there a way to obtain 2 or more separate indexes, each belonging to a a separate list.

For e.g

Index1 for list 1

Index2 for list 2

Idealistically I'd want this to occur in a single for loop.

P.S Am still very new to programming as a whole, so I only can grasp basic concepts like looping, objects, data structures etc, so nothing to technical ;)

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Hey Ashwini, i'll post in italics in the Q! :)

Comment: It is still not clear to me what exactly do you want, but I guess what you need to do here is change `index+1` to `index*2+1`.

Comment: Hey Ashwini, really the details of the Q is irrelevant, actually am going to simply the Q, I think it should be.

Comment: can you show us some input and expected output???

Comment: Hey Hack, I actually did in the original, but I think that any code snippets would complicate the Q, since it's a simple aim.

Comment: There are many ways to obtain indices from/for separate ```list```s in a loop.  Without something a little more concrete in your question, it will be impossible to give a specific answer.  What are the constraints?  What condition selects the separate indices? Is the condition the same for both lists? Example *input* and expected *output* are a minimum requirement for coding questions and we typically expect to see the code that you are working on (a minimal example) but are having trouble with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you right you are not searching for zipping two lists together but doing something like mapping each element of a to each element of b? Like the cartesian product of two sets?

So for two lists:

```
a = ['1', '2', '3']
b = ['ba', 'bb']
```

You could iterate them both for every element like this using list comprehensions:

```
[(x,y) for x in a for y in b]
```

This generates the following output:

```
1 ba
1 bb
2 ba
2 bb
3 ba
3 bb
```

For further information on list comprehensions look up this: [PythonDocs - List Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

You can get the same result with nested for loops:

```
for x in a:
    for y in b:
        print(x + " " + y)
```

In addition to that, the cartesion products comes with the itertools:

```
import itertools
for x,y in itertools.product(a,b):
    print(x + " " + y)
```

This also generates the same output as the nested for loops or the list comprehension.

**EDIT:**

Regarding to your comment (I thought you do not want zip?) izip e.g. is exactly what you want.

For input:

```
a = ['1', '2', '3']
b = ['ba', 'bb']
```

An izip like this:

```
import itertools
for x,y in itertools.izip(a,b):
    print(x + " " + y)
```

Would generate the following output:

```
1 ba
2 bb
```

Comment: Feel free (and don't forget^^) to ask additional stuff if something remained unclear...or vote & accept the answer if all is fine (:

Comment: Ok no like really, you need to know that this is pretty much the best answer that really could of existed, shame I can't +1 you